# Postgresql update a daterange column from 2 date columns

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `baking_events` and it has a `start_date` and `end_date` field. Now I've decided that I would like to take advantage of all of the nice range operators, so I add a new `daterange` column to the table called `duration`.

I would like to run a query to update `duration` on my `baking_events` table so that it is equal to `[start_date, end_date]` for each record before I delete the `start_date` and `end_date` columns.

Is there a way to do this in postgres without having to loop through each individual record? Something like: `UPDATE TABLE baking_events SET duration = [start_date, end_date]::daterange` (this query obviously does not work, but should give you an idea of what I want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [daterange constructor:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

```
select daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '[]');

        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2018-01-01,2019-01-01)
(1 row)
```

Although '[]' is specified here, on display the value will be converted to canonical form, since `daterange` is a [discrete range type.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE)

The update command may look like this:

```
UPDATE baking_events 
SET duration = daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]');
```

Note, that after adding and updating the new column the table is [not normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you should consider dropping the `start_date` and `end_date` columns.